# How can I autoformat/indent C code in vim?

Tags: c, vim, code-formatting

When I copy code from another file, the formatting is messed up, like this:

```
fun()
{
for(...)
{
for(...)
{
if(...)
{
}
}
}
}
```

How can I autoformat this code in vim?

Comment: For anyone looking to format and not just indent the code, the second answer (mine) addresses that. If you just want to fix indenting, the accepted answer is the simplest way.

Answer (score 692, accepted):

Try the following keystrokes:

```
gg=G
```

Explanation: `gg` goes to the top of the file, `=` is a command to fix the indentation and `G` tells it to perform the operation to the end of the file.

Comment: this only indents the code. can something not be done to AUTOFORMAT the entire thing?

Comment: @Ton van: [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355834/auto-format-c-file-in-vim/4236918#4236918) for the difference (Could not have explained here in comments).

Comment: -1 This only fixes indentation, not formatting (which was what being asked for).

Comment: @oligofren The OP's example only included indentation errors and he accepts the answer, so I guess that's what he meant.

Comment: @oligofren Also, he specified he copies the code from another file, which makes indentation problems more likely than other formatting problems.

Comment: Suggested edit: change title to "Auto indent C code in Vim" otherwise, some people (like me) find this answer while looking for the AStyle answer.

Comment: I haven't known such combination. I used == for single line, but I thought that = works only in visual mode,

Comment: You can then hit <C-o><C-O> to go back to where you were.

Comment: In "Ex mode" (which you typically enter with :), the equivalent is `:%normal ==` (where % means all lines in the current buffer--aka file in vim's memory--and == means autoindent the current line). This approach allows you to limit auto-indent by line number, like `:5,10normal ==` (meaning, lines 5-10). And you can abbreviate `normal` to `norm` to save typing, as well eliminate the space: `:%norm==`.

Comment: Warning for readers: this set tabstop to `8`. Try `astyle`.

Comment: @asuka you can `set tabstop=4`.

Answer (score 94):

I like to use the program Artistic Style. According to their [website](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/):

> Artistic Style is a source code indenter, formatter, and beautifier for the C, C++, C# and Java programming languages.

It runs in Window, Linux and Mac. It will do things like indenting, replacing tabs with spaces or vice-versa, putting spaces around operations however you like (converting `if(x<2)` to if `( x<2 )` if that's how you like it), putting braces on the same line as function definitions, or moving them to the line below, etc. All the options are controlled by command line parameters.

In order to use it in vim, just set the formatprg option to it, and then use the gq command. So, for example, I have in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp set formatprg=astyle\ -T4pb
```

so that whenever I open a .cpp file, formatprg is set with the options I like. Then, I can type gg to go to the top of the file, and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to format the entire file according to my standards. If I only need to reformat a single function, I can go to the top of the function, then type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and it will reformat just that function.

The options I have for astyle, `-T4pb`, are just my preferences. You can look through [their docs](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html), and change the options to have it format the code however you like.

Here's a demo. Before astyle:

```
int main(){if(x<2){x=3;}}

float test()
{
if(x<2)
x=3;
}
```

After astyle (gggqG):

```
int main()
{
    if (x < 2)
    {
        x = 3;
    }
}

float test()
{
    if (x < 2)
        x = 3;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything like this for other formats; ruby, xml, json, etc.?

Comment: @Ryan check vim-autoformat, see answer below. BTW vim-autoformat also uses astyle among others.

Comment: Thank you!  I was beginning to think I was the only person in the word who didn't want their opening brackets on the same line as the function declaration!

Answer (score 34):

The builtin command for properly indenting the code has already been mentioned (`gg=G`). If you want to *beautify* the code, you'll need to use an external application like [indent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_%28Unix%29). Since `%` denotes the current file in ex mode, you can use it like this:

```
:!indent %
```

Comment: Before using this command, ensure to do `sudo apt install indent` to install the indent utility.

Answer (score 24):

I find that `clang-format` works well.

There are some example keybindings in the [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)

I prefer to use the `equalprg` binding in vim. This allows you to invoke `clang-format` with `G=gg` or other `=` indent options.

Just put the following in your .vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp setlocal equalprg=clang-format
```

Comment: Need to install it first, e.g  for ubuntu 16.04+: `sudo apt install clang-format`

Answer (score 19):

The plugin vim-autoformat lets you format your buffer (or buffer selections) with a single command: https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat. It uses external format programs for that, with a fallback to vim's indentation functionality.

Answer (score 9):

I like `indent` as mentioned above, but most often I want to format only a small section of the file that I'm working on. Since `indent` can take code from stdin, its really simple:

1. Select the block of code you want to format with <kbd>V</kbd> or the like.
2. Format by typing `:!indent`.

`astyle` takes stdin too, so you can use the same trick there.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add, that in order to prevent it from being messed up in the first place you can type `:set paste` before pasting. After pasting, you can type `:set nopaste` for things like js-beautify and indenting to work again.

Comment: I use `:set paste!` for this, which toggles the paste value instead of setting it. This makes it easier to turn off as you can simply scroll back a few commands and press enter.

Comment: You can also setup a hotkey for this. I wish I didn't have to but it's apparently a necessary evil.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try the followings
  $indent -kr -i8 *.c

Hope it's useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

Their is a tool called `indent`. You can download it with `apt-get install indent`, then run `indent my_program.c`.

Comment: This GNU tool sucks is weird... I did not like it!

Comment: its very customiseable. I use it as cb (C beautify) in my .bashrc as: alias cb='indent -kr -l200 -lc200 -cli2 -i4 -nut -linux $1'

Answer (score -1):

For a good overview and demo of many of the options mentioned here, @Gavin-Freeborn has a great video on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM_uIwSucPU

It covers some Vim plugins as well as built-in capabilities such as `=`, `gq`, and `formatprg`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why this is voted down; I found the video far more useful than trying to sort through all the options here.  I'd be happy to add further description here in this answer of the capabilities mentioned; I'd just felt like the other answers already filled out that part.

Comment: This is a forum based on the written word.  To refer, with no relevant detals, the reader to a video is likely to be ill received by the SO community.

Comment: @erik258 - Thanks, that seems fair.  The video has a fair bit that would need to summarized beyond the `=` `gq` and `formatprg` that I tersely mention in the answer.  It's still a really useful video; if I can find time (and the recollection) to go back and add relevant transcript excerpts, I will.  YouTube seems to have dropped providing transcripts, at least for non-premium accounts, so it'll take some extra effort.  In any case, I really appreciate the explanation!