# Is there some mean to delete or fulfill whitespace in Code?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Ex, My C source code like this:

```
static float             getYuvMemoryRatio( int  format       )  {  
}
```

Is there some command to format my code as below:

```
static float getYuvMemoryRatio( int format ){
}
```

Comment: does this help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355834/auto-format-c-file-in-vim

Comment: You could always shell this out to an external command, e.g. astyle, bcpp, or indent. Recently I started using clang-format which is also nice but still in heavy development.

Comment: Does "Ex" mean "For example" here?

Comment: @innaM, yes Ex means for example, isn't fit?

Comment: @mcalex,  Autoformat can't strip the excess whitespace.

Comment: When you tag your questions with "vim", "Ex" might mean something quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fllowing is my config and verified by myself on c source code
1.Install Autoformat  and astyle 
2.add the following snip in your vimrc：

```
 398     " autoformat{
 399     noremap <F2> :Autoformat<CR><CR>
 400     "autocmd FileType * let "g:formatprg_".&filetype = "astyle"
 401     "autocmd FileType * let "g:formatprg_args_".&filetype = "--mode=cs --style=ansi -pcUHs4"
 402     "echo &filetype tell you the suffix of formatprg_
 403     let g:formatprg_c = "astyle"
 404     let g:formatprg_args_c = "--mode=cs --style=ansi -fDpcUs4"
 405     "let g:formatprg_args_cs = "--mode=cs --style=ansi -TU4pb"                                                                                                      
 406     " }
```

Everything works perfect for my code now. You can type "man astyle" and get to know the different option meaning