# what is the quickest way to set the codes into well formatted in gvim?

Tags: vim

The raw form code is as the following:

```
class A(object):
       def __init__(self):
              self.__private()
              self.public()
       def __private(self):
              print('A.__private()')
       def public(self):
              print 'A.public()'
```

What is the most quickest way to set into the well formatted form as the following in gvim?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private()
        self.public()
    def __private(self):
        print('A.__private()')
    def public(self):
        print 'A.public()'
```

Comment: Try this command `gg=G`. For full explanation on what it does, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2355848/1144203).