# Auto formatting code in vim when saving .cpp file

Tags: c++, vim

I have read this [How can I autoformat/indent C code in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355834/how-can-i-autoformat-indent-c-code-in-vim) about how to format C/C++ code, but I want to autoformat the code when I'm saving the file, like how vim-go calls `gofmt` when saving Golang code.

How can I configure my vimrc? I'm using clang-format, and have installed [vim-clang-format](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format) with spf13vim using Vundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

> - `g:clang_format#detect_style_file`
>
> When this variable's value is `1`, vim-clang-format automatically detects the style file like `.clang-format` or `_clang-format` and applies the style to formatting.

So this code should be in the `.vimrc`:

```
let g:clang_format#auto_format=1
```