# How do I format qw lists using perltidy?

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

Assuming a Perl script such:

```
my @a = (
    1,
    2,
    3
) ;

my @b = qw(
    foo
    bar
    baz
) ;
```

executing `perltidy` with options: `perltidy -nopro -ci=4 -boc -sts`, I get a different closing parens alignment between the array and the `qw` list:

```
my @a = (
    1,
    2,
    3
) ;

my @b = qw(
    foo
    bar
    baz
    ) ; # <== misplaced parens, I want it to be at column 1
```

I want to get the closing parens of the `qw` list aligned to column 1. What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?

## UPDATE

Thanks to the suggestion of @toolic I disabled my `.perltidyrc` file  (my bad, I missed to do it before) and searched for the rule causing the misformatting of qw lists and found that is the `--space-terminal-semicolon` that alters the closing parens alignment only for qw lists.

I updated the perltidy options in the above issue description.
I don't really understand if it may be a bug of `perltidy` or not.

Anyway, the issue is now reproducible and seems that I have to choose the lesser evil between having the closing parens of the `qw` lists misaligned or giving up the space before the semicolon at the end of the statements :-(

Comment: The version is v20190601 and bump.. Yes, I have it. I missed to comment it during my command line test :'( Lets try whitout .perltidyrc dotfile

Comment: @toolic great!! You saved my day. Commenting all rules in my `.perltidyrc` dotfile the qw list gets well formatted.  I have now to search for the wrong rule in my config file.
Thansk and post your answer for getting the upvote!!

Comment: Uhhmm.. I found and removed the conflicting rule `-sts` (--space-terminal-semicolon) and the qw list are well formatted now, but I can't get the space before the semicolon at the end of the line.

Comment: Have you tried to use `vim` to reformat perl code? It might be what you looking for. [How can I autoformat/indent C code in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355834/how-can-i-autoformat-indent-c-code-in-vim/2355848), [Fix indentation](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Fix_indentation), [7 Vim Tips That Changed My Life With Demo](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/7-vim-tips-that-changed-my-life/).

Comment: @Polar Bear, I don't directly call the perltidy linter, but it's called by a code formatter plugin of Sublime Text editor we use in our company. Anyway I'll open an issue to github and meanwhile I can tolerate some misplaced closing parens in qw lists :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce your result.  I do not have a `.perltidyrc` command file, which can have options that are not on your command line.

You can use the [perltidy -nopro](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/view/bin/perltidy) option to ignore any `.perltidyrc` command file, if you have one.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I have updated the issue too because the strange beahaviour still persists, I guess you should now reproduce it. The conflicting option seems to be the --space-terminal-semicolon that alters the closing parens alignment only for the qw lists.